# R barplot - keep same colours after sorting

Tags: r, sorting, plot, bar-chart

I want to plot percentages for 3 variables (a,b,c) one after the others. So I have a matrix (%) for a set of activities for variable **a**, **b** and **c**.

```
dta = structure(c(0.0073, 0.1467, 0.0111, 0.0294, 0.0451, 0.0031, 0.1823, 
        0.0452, 0.2212, 0.1123, 7e-04, 0.1138, 0.0723, 0.1649, 0.0634), 
        .Dim = c(5L, 3L), 
        .Dimnames = list(c("c Work", "e Travel/Commute", 
                           "f Cooking", "g Housework", "h Odd jobs"),
                         c("a", "b", "c")))
```

However, I would like to plot each variables sorted and but keeping the same colours for the set of activities.

So this is the colours of the activities.

```
library(RColorBrewer) 

rc = c(brewer.pal(n = 5, name = 'Set2'))  

kol = list()
kol$act <- c("c Work", "e Travel/Commute", "f Cooking", "g Housework", "h Odd jobs" )
kol$colours <- rc
kol = as.data.frame(kol)

               act colours
1           c Work #66C2A5
2 e Travel/Commute #FC8D62
3        f Cooking #8DA0CB
4      g Housework #E78AC3
5       h Odd jobs #A6D854
```

So here are my barplots

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
barplot(dta[,1], horiz = T, las = 2, col = kol$colours)
barplot(dta[,2], horiz = T, las = 2, col = kol$colours)
barplot(dta[,3], horiz = T, las = 2, col = kol$colours)
```

So I want is to sort by keep the same colours for the activities

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
barplot(sort(dta[,1]), horiz = T, las = 2)
barplot(sort(dta[,2]), horiz = T, las = 2)
barplot(sort(dta[,3]), horiz = T, las = 2)
```

How can I make it "match" ?

Comment: try `barplot(sort(dta[,1]), horiz = T, las = 2, col=kol$colours[match(names(sort(dta[,1])), kol$act)])` (so, in other words, to make it "matched", try function `match` ;-) )

Comment: @CathG - thanks ! I was unsure how to use `match` properly ! why dont you post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `match` to match the names of the "entities" and the desired colours, for example, for the first column:

```
kol$colours[match(names(sort(dta[,1])), kol$act)]
```

so, to obtain your barplot, just do:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2), mar=c(5, 8, 4, 1)) # also modifying the margins to make the names fit in
for (i in 1:3) {
    barplot(sort(dta[,i]), horiz = T, las = 2, col=kol$colours[match(names(sort(dta[, i])), kol$act)])
}
```

[image]